# Login with multiple login credientials

Tags: java

I am creating an app for my company and I am very new to coding and app development. I am currently working on a login screen that has multiple login credentials. But I am not sure how to set it up properly. I was able to make it work with a single login but now I am trying to get it to work with more than just 1. So here is my setup I just think it is a formatting error. The Error I get is that"" }else{ "unexpected token" "" Any help would be great thanks in advance!!!

```
private void validate(String userName, String userPassword) {
    if ((userName.equals("Admin")) && (userPassword.equals("Pass")) ||
        ((userName.equals("Shop")) && (userPassword.equals("4321"))));
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}else{
        counter--;

        Info.setText("No of attempts remaining: " + String.valueOf(counter));

        if (counter== 0){
            Login.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: The semicolon at the end of `(userPassword.equals("4321"))));`. Due to this semicolon, your compiler thinks there is no statement after the `if`.

Comment: Check your `{` and `}`.

Comment: you need another ) after (userPassword.equals("Pass"))

Comment: The `}` at the start of that `else` line... What `{` is that closing?

Comment: The error is related to the semi colon currently as pointed out by @S.L.Barth. Just replace it with `{`

Comment: Also - this is a very bad way of making a login screen. The password is hard-coded and present as plaintext in the app. It will do for a proof-of-concept, but is completely unsuitable for a production environment.

Comment: S.L. Barth how would you recommend I code this then? I only need a hand full of logins. Like I said I am new to this and I don't really know of another way. Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you're logging on to a server (which is usually why you need a login screen), you make an HTTPS connection to the server. And send the credentials over that connection. Then, you let the server do the verification.

Comment: I guess I could do it that way and have the server do the verification, though I don't know how to do that and I am guessing it would be a bit more complex than having a couple pre-saved login credentials.Then again i dont know.

Comment: I played with all the different fixes proposed and nothing seems to get it fully to work. If I remove the semicolon after ("4321)))) it says the Intent intent statement is not allowed here. Not sure what to do about that. If I add the extra ) like Stultuske says then it says || unexpected token also says i need a semicolon after the next line but when i add it says unexpected.

Comment: You need to learn a bit more about Java. The problems you are experiencing now, are there because you don't yet understand the Java syntax. Have a look at the [official Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). Work through "Getting started" and "Learning the Java language"; the rest if you feel like it. After that, you'll be better able to understand the error messages you are getting.

Comment: Two tips about learning Java: (1) in your exercise programs, deliberately introduce mistakes and see what happens. You'll get familiar with the error messages that way. (2) Try to understand the results of what you are doing. Your purpose is to not just know _how_, but also _why_.